# Characterization of isometries on Riemannian manifolds of positive (non-negative) curvature analogous to Bishop-O'Neill theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, isometry

Bishop and O'Neill in

*Bishop, R. L.; O’Neill, B.*, [**Manifolds of negative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1995057), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 145, 1-49 (1969). [ZBL0191.52002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.52002).

characterized isometry of Riemannian manifolds of non-positive curvature which states that:

> **Theorem (Bishop-O'Neill):** Let $\varphi$ be an isometry of $M$. Then
> exactly one of the following is true:
>
> 1. $\varphi$ has a fixed point;
> 2. $\varphi$ translates a (unique) geodesic;
> 3. $f_\varphi :M\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f_\varphi(x) = d^2(x,\varphi(x))$ has no minimum.

I wonder if there is any analogous for  positive (non-negative) curvature? If the answer is no, What efforts have been made so far for similar theorems?

**Edit (after @LeeMosher comment)**:  $M$ is simply-connected, complete, Riemannian manifold of sectional curvature $K \leq C < 0$. Othewise there is a counterexample. (E.g. [see below Lee Mosher's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842456/characterization-of-isometries-on-riemannian-manifolds-of-positive-non-negative#comment7927371_3842456))

Comment: Which theorem in that paper are you referring to? I ask because some hypotheses are missing: Assuming only that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold of non-positive curvature, there are simple counterexamples.

Comment: Proposition 4.2.  I think the authors considered all manifolds to be of non-positive curvature. What example?

Comment: There are isometries of compact hyperbolic surfaces which have no fixed point, do not translate any geodesic, and $f_\varphi$ has a minimum. Take, for example, a nontrivial deck transformation of any connected, regular covering space of degree $\ge 2$ over any closed hyperbolic surface.

Comment: @Lee:  I agree your isometries don't satisfy 1 and 3, but how do you see it doesn't translate a geodesic?

Comment: What I wrote regarding 2 is not quite right: it should have been "do not translate a unique geodesic", i.e. there are examples that translate more than one closed geodesic.

Comment: One such example is the 180 degree rotation of [this genus $3$ surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_g_surface#/media/File:Triple_torus_array.png) around an axis that goes through the middle hole.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Sorry, I did not actually read the Bishop and O'Neill paper, and I saw this theorem in another paper referred to the above paper. here are the assumptions (in introduction section of second paper): _$M$ will denote a simply-connected, complete, Riemannian manifold of sectional curvature $K \leq C < 0$_